# What did we learn about Trump's strategy to achieve peace in the Middle East after his May 2017 visit to Israel and Palestine?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, israel, palestine, middle-east

Trump famously declared that he is the one to bring peace to the Middle East region. He recently visited Israel and Palestine, meeting with Netanjahu and Abbas.

Did he mention the peace process during the visit or following the visit? Did he exhibit any views or made any endorsements that facilitate or impede progress toward peace in the Middle East, e.g. about the continuing extension of settlements, the status of East-Jerusalem, etc.?

And if there were any, how did the Israeli government and the Palestinian authorities as well as Hamas react to these statements by Trump?

Comment: "President Trump’s plane hadn’t cleared Israeli airspace Tuesday before writers in the Middle East and at home began trying to figure out what the visit had meant." [¹](http://nymag.com/daily/intelligencer/2017/05/trumps-messy-mostly-successful-israel-visit.html) (the article basically gives an answer) - so the question is of interest. Would anyone of the close-voters mind telling me what is 'too broad' so that I can edit it to fit?

Answer (score 4):

He didn't mention any exact details in his speeches, apart from **reiterating that he is committed to helping Israelis and Palestinians achieve a peace agreement** and that **making peace will not be easy**.

Below are excerpts from his speeches relating to the peace process that Trump made in Israel and in Palestine.

#### May 22, 2017 — [Remarks by President Trump and Prime Minister Netanyahu in Joint Statement](https://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2017/05/22/remarks-president-trump-and-prime-minister-netanyahu-joint-statement)

> We are willing to work together.  I believe that a new level of partnership is possible and will happen -- one that will bring greater safety to this region, greater security to the United States, and greater prosperity to the world.  This includes a renewed effort at peace between the Israelis and the Palestinians, and I thank the Prime Minister for his commitment to pursuing the peace process.  He’s working very hard at it.  It’s not easy.  I’ve heard it’s one of the toughest deals of all, but I have a feeling that we’re going to get there eventually, I hope.

#### May 22, 2017 — [Remarks by President Trump at the Israel Museum](https://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2017/05/23/remarks-president-trump-israel-museum)

> My administration is committed to pursuing such a coalition, and we have already made substantial progress during this trip.  We know, for instance, that both Israelis and Palestinians seek lives of hope for their children.  And we know that peace is possible if we put aside the pain and disagreements of the past and commit together to finally resolving this crisis, which has dragged on for nearly half a century or more.
>
> As I have repeatedly said, I am personally committed to helping Israelis and Palestinians achieve a peace agreement, and I had a meeting this morning with President Abbas and can tell you that the Palestinians are ready to reach for peace.  I know you’ve heard it before.  I am telling you -- that’s what I do.  They are ready to reach for peace.
>
> In my meeting with my very good friend, Benjamin, I can tell you also that he is reaching for peace.  He wants peace.  He loves people.  He especially loves the Israeli people.  Benjamin Netanyahu wants peace.
>
> Making peace, however, will not be easy.  We all know that.  Both sides will face tough decisions.  But with determination, compromise, and the belief that peace is possible, Israelis and Palestinians can make a deal.

#### **May 23, 2017** — [Remarks by President Trump and President Abbas of the Palestinian Authority in Joint Statements](https://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2017/05/23/remarks-president-trump-and-president-abbas-palestinian-authority-joint)

> As I discussed with President Abbas in Washington earlier this month, I am committed to trying to achieve a peace agreement between the Israelis and the Palestinians and I intend to do everything I can to help them achieve that goal.  President Abbas assures me he is ready to work toward that goal in good faith.  And Prime Minister Netanyahu has promised the same.  I look forward to working with these leaders toward a lasting peace.
>
> [ ... ]
>
> I also firmly believe that if Israel and the Palestinians can make peace, it will begin a process of peace all throughout the Middle East.  And that would be an amazing accomplishment.

Comment: Your first paragraph actually answered the question. So apparently he wasn't mentioning any of the critical issues (East-Jerusalem, settlements,…), so there is nothing concrete yet.